# C++17 -- mapping types of member variables to std::optionals

Tags: c++, templates

How could I take some structure:

```cpp
template<typename T>
typedef struct something_t {
  int x;
  int y;
  T z;
} something_t;
```

And create a utility type (possibly combined with some macros) which maps it to the same-shaped structure, but full of `std::optionals` instead. In other words, how would I write the `partial` struct in the following code,

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct partial<T> { using type = ??? };

template<typename T>
using partial_something_t = partial<something_t<T>>::type;
```

...which would result in `partial_something_t` having this definition:

```cpp
template<typename T>
typedef struct partial_something_t {
  std::optional<int> x;
  std::optional<int> y;
  std::optional<T> z;
} partial_something_t;
```

Comment: This requires language reflection which C++ doesn't have. You could achieve it with meta-programming.

Comment: If I were willing to also use macros, would that help?

Comment: Maybe, but it won't be easy.

Comment: Hence this question :)

Comment: You can do it with tuples: `std::tuple<Ts...>` can easily be transformed into `std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...>`.

Comment: By the way `template<..> typedef` is illegal and `typedef struct` is generally not needed in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the definition of `something_t`, you can change it this way:

```
template <template<typename> typename Wrapper, typename T>
struct new_something_t {
  Wrapper<int> x;
  Wrapper<int> y;
  Wrapper<T> z;
};
```

Then define a alias:

```
template <typename What> 
using Id = What;
```

Now your original `something_t<T>` becomes `new_something_t<Id, T>` and `partial_something_t<T>` is `new_something_t<std::optional, T>`.

Comment: Cool! This is doable and avoids duplication nicely.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use local includes with macro overloading. Create a new .inl.h file that contains the inner structure some kind this way:

```
BEGIN_TEMPLATE_STRUCT(something_t)
  DECLARE_MEMBER(int, x)
  DECLARE_MEMBER(int, y)
  DECLARE_MEMBER(T, z)
END_TEMPLATE_STRUCT
```

Then create maybe two different header files (or only one as you prefer) that define the concrete macro definitions on their own, using push and pop_macro. Place the push_macros right before the include of this .inl.h file with the raw declaration of your struct, include the file and then don't forget to pop_macro to have a clean state afterwards. Header one then defines BEGIN_TEMPLATE_STRUCT as something_t and header two as partial_something_t and the sub-macros according to your wanted final types (DECLARE_MEMBER as std::optional...). The benefit of this approach is, that you have a minimal basic representation of your data that can be adapted to more complex ones. The major drawback is the (error-prone) macro-usage itself and some work to write at least more complex members like method types.

Comment: If you are willing to change the definition of `something_t`, C++ has better ways of doing that, without any macros.

Comment: No, the definition of something_t gets not affected this way if you define the transforming macros in the right way. The macro performs exactly the way MHebes wants it to do. Finally you have two different structs with the desired properties. C++17 might have some nice template-usage advantages (via tuples for instance) that can help here but it still has no direct way for named member intrusion, i.e. reflection actually.

Comment: The macro may perform but it is ugly as hell, tools will choke on it and people will scratch their heads looking at it.

Comment: At least for simple structs, most modern development tools perform well here since you don't need the macro to be visible on struct usage side/the "outside world". With a minimum effort of clean placement, you can avoid almost all drawbacks of macros here. But yes, it would be always better to have some kind of language based approaches here I admit.